# How to pick specific li element which is generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I couldn't pick a specific li element on click which is generated dynamically. please help.

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() 
 {
$('#id1').on('click', 'li', function(e) 
{ 
 var val = $(this).find('.pick').attr('data-val1');
 console.log(val); // returns only first value for every click
 });
 });
```

Dynamically created HTML

```
 var x = document.getElementById("id1");
x.innerHTML= x.innerHTML + '<li class="pick" data-val1="'+i+'"></li>' // where i is a incremental counter
```

HTML

```
<ul id ="id1">
 // li adds here
</ul>
```

Comment: Maybe `var val = $(this).find('.pick').last().attr('data-val1');`

Comment: The concatenation is wrong. Is that a typo?

Comment: returns last value only for every click

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy no typo error.

Comment: also can you share the relevant html and where the script related to creation of the new `li` element

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id1').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    var val = $(this).attr('data-val1');
    snippet.log('clciekd: ' + val); // returns only first value for every click
  });

  var i = 0;
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('<li />', {
      'data-val1': ++i,
      text: i
    }).appendTo('#id1');
  })
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="id1"></ul>
<button>Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/nec47v8d/

You can use this **JQUERY**

```
$('#id1 li.pick').click(function (e) {
    var val = $(this).attr('data-val1');
    alert(val)
});
```

Comment: it is in javascript function so i need it in this way

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get you